# Getting wrong result in sorting Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I'm practicing C# and wrote the code below excluding the line beginning "`Array.Sort`....". The output was as expected (i.e. "5,7,2,").

When I included the line "`Array.Sort`..." I was expecting to get "2,5,7," but got the output "5,5,7,", i.e. the 2 had disappeared and had been replaced by a 5 somehow. Could anyone help explain why (to a beginner)?

```
namespace ConsoleApplication33
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = new int[3] { 5, 7, 2 };

            for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(numbers[i] + " , ");
                Array.Sort(numbers);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Array.sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.array.sort(v=vs.110).aspx) is a method that doesn't require any kind of loop iteration,, just invoke it is more than enough

your issue is caused because you are looping AND sorting 3 times which is completely unnecessary...
now, you are taking the element at position **i**, then sorting and doing this 3 times... look at the animation for more illustrative explanation

[image]
you are sorting correct but are reading the elements of the array index by index  which is not correct and not necessary

**remove the hole for loop and  just call Array.Sort(numbers);**

```
//for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++)
//{
     //Console.Write(numbers[i] + " , ");
     Array.Sort(numbers);
//}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a `for` loop to sort. Just `Array.Sort` should sorts your array:

```
int[] numbers = new int[3] { 5, 7, 2 };
Array.Sort(numbers);
```

After you sorted the array, you can print the sorted array like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write(numbers[i] + " , ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You sort in a loop, writing the `i` value before. So your code works like this

- Write first item (5)
- Sort the array
- Write the second item (now 5)
- Sort the array
- Write the third item (now 7)

You probably wanted to sort the array, then write it out:

```
int[] numbers = new int[3] { 5, 7, 2 };

Array.Sort(numbers);

for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(numbers[i] + " , ");
}
```

As an aside, you could also use `string.Join` and avoid the loop (and trailing comma):

```
var commaSeparatedNums = string.Join(", ", numbers);
Console.Write(commaSeparatedNums);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the array in the loop. The sort changes the array only the first time that it is applied; second and third invocations of the sort make no changes to the array.

The first printout happens on the unsorted array; the second printout happens on the sorted array. The first time around `5` is the initial number; the second time, `5` is in the middle. That is why you see `5` printed twice.

You need to sort the array once before going into the printing loop in order to fix this problem:

```
Array.Sort(numbers);
for (int i = 0; i< numbers.Length; i++) {
    Console.Write(numbers[i] + " , ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I get it now following your explanations. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Array.Sort without loop. If you wan to sort an array.

```
int[] numbers = new int[3] { 5, 7, 2 };
Array.Sort(numbers);
```